# Find the Cartesian form of the parametric equations: $x=2\sin^2(\theta)$, $y=7\cos^2(\theta)$

Tags: parametric

I am trying to find the cartesian form of the parametric expressions $x=2\sin^2(\theta)$, $y=7\cos^2(\theta)$. I have $x=2-cos^2(\theta)$ but i can't work it after that.

Answer (score 0):

$$sin^2(\theta)+cos^2(\theta)=1$$
$$\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{7}=1$$

Comment: Also with the restrictions $x, y \ge 0$ (which also implies $x \le 2$, $y \le 7$).

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks :)